# Как присоединиться к процессу?

Tags: c#

Как приаттачиться (отаттачиться) к процессу в VS 10, исспользуя клавиши, чтоб не дергать мышью?

Comment: ctrl alt p

Comment: Не, ну если надо в процессе работы, то никакого другого способа, кроме как инжекта DLL`ки в чужое адресное пространство я не вижу =)

Answer (score 1):

Штатным образом — никак.

Можно добавить макрос, который приаттачится к нужному процессу, а затем в настройках клавиатуры (Tools -> Options -> Keyboard), повесить хоткей на этот макрос.

Например:

```
Public Sub AttachShortcut()
  For Each proc In DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses 
    If proc.Name = "имя_процесса" Then
      proc.Attach()
      Exit Sub
    End IF
  Next
End Sub
```

Аналогично для деаттача.

Comment: А у вас Ctrl-Alt-P не работает?

Comment: Работает :). Но там надо больше нажатий клавиш совершать: табы, стрелочки, энтеры. А тут один раз сделал и готов.